# Change values from - to + and also copy them to a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Members here helped me build this code.

I would like, instead of converting all the negative values to positive in one sheet it take the whole row which would look like this:

[image]

and move that row into a new worksheet with all the numbers converted to positive.

```
Sub ntp()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("originalNeg")
        For Each cel In .Range("I2:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
            If cel.value < 0 Then cel.value = Abs(cel.value)
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @jsotola the code is in my question sir. Not sure what you are talking about. sorry

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be to load the data into an array, process it and then write it to the new worksheet.

```
Sub ntp2()
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("originalNeg")
        values = .Range("A1" , .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).value
    End With

    For x = 2 To UBound(values)
        If values(x, 9) < 0 Then values(x, 9) = Abs(values(x, 9))
    Next

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheet")
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(values), UBound(values, 2)).value = values
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the value `x` is known to be negative, why not just assign `-x` instead of `abs(x)`? OTOH, one could assign the absolute value regardless of the sign, without testing first. Both methods seem like a waste of performance.

Comment: Thomas the code above is not working . Is giving me an error and when i click debug is asking me to fix this " values = .Range("A1" & .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).value"

Comment: Thomas this works fine but the problem is that when i try to assign this macro to a button it gives me an error message that says "Reference must be to a macro sheet". I have three buttons in which i assigned three different macros in the original sheet which consists of the original data. After i click the first one, the macro works fine, it does what i asked it to do, the second macro extracts all the rows with negative values and paste those to a new sheet (it creates a new sheet by itself and pastes all the data there )

Comment: now the macro that you helped me with above i want to take all those rows with the negative values and create a new sheet by itself and not only paste those rows with the negative values but also convert them to positive. All these macros i want assign to buttons and run them from the original sheet. I did this with the first two macros, i am having trouble doing this for the one that you build for me above.

Comment: @user1016274 working with with arrays is super fast.  Unless you are doing 10's of millions of assignments the difference will be negligible.

Comment: @OneaboveAll experience is the best teacher.  After watching these videos [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) you will be able to find your own solution.